# Android: How to set images to image resource based on Set<String>?

Tags: android, gridview, sharedpreferences

I am new Android Developer.
Is this the correct way to set images to image resource based on Set or not?

```
image.setImageResource(ListActivity.image_items[Integer.parseInt(data1.get(position))]);
```

Comment: post your image_items array and data1 objects

Comment: nest too many invocations is a VERY BAD habit.

Answer (score 0):

I use that :

You have add an image in the drawable resources :

xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image"
    />
```

Java

```
ImageView ImageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1ID);
ImageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
```

-----OR-----

Maybe you want use android native resources ?
I have find your question because i'm look for :

xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_offline" 
    />
```

//Android studio generate this xml if i drag and drop an image view from palette editor on to my layout preview.

Java

```
ImageView ImageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1ID);
ImageView1.setImageResource( "sorry i don't know" );
```

Good luck.